# Queue Quick sort not sorting and printing out random strings [C++]

Tags: c++, sorting, queue, quicksort

This code should take 5 integers from the user and put them into a list and sort them. I am trying to demonstrate that you can sort a queue using a quicksort but it prints out random strings/variable names mixed with letters such as emp1temp1, 9urrentID. I'm not too familiar with how to use queues but I do know that push adds to the front of the queue, pop removes the item at the front of the queue and front and back looks at the first and last values.

```
struct PatientDetails {
    int ID;
};
queue<PatientDetails> unorderedQueue;
void quickSortIDQueue(queue<PatientDetails> patient);
void addPatient();

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        addPatient();
    }

    queue<PatientDetails> Queue;

    for (int i = 0; i < unorderedQueue.size(); i++) {
        unorderedQueue.push(unorderedQueue.front());
        Queue.push(unorderedQueue.front());
        unorderedQueue.pop();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < unorderedQueue.size(); i++) {
        PatientDetails id = Queue.front();
        cout << id.ID + " ";
        Queue.pop();
    }
    cout << endl;
    quickSortIDQueue(unorderedQueue);
    for (int i = 0; i < unorderedQueue.size(); i++) {
        PatientDetails id = unorderedQueue.front();
        cout << id.ID + " ";
        unorderedQueue.pop();
    }
    cout << endl;
    string text;
    cin >> text;
    return 0;
}

void quickSortIDQueue(queue<PatientDetails> patient) {
    queue<PatientDetails> temp1;
    queue<PatientDetails> temp2;
    queue<PatientDetails> temp3;
    PatientDetails pivot = patient.back();

    PatientDetails CurrentID;

    while (patient.size() > 0) {
        CurrentID = patient.front();
        patient.pop();
        if (CurrentID.ID < pivot.ID) {
            temp1.push(CurrentID);
        }
        else if (CurrentID.ID == pivot.ID) {
            temp2.push(CurrentID);
        }
        else {
            temp3.push(CurrentID);
        }

        if (temp1.size() > 1){
            quickSortIDQueue(temp1);
        }
        if (temp3.size() > 1){
            quickSortIDQueue(temp3);
        }

    }
    while (temp1.size() > 0) {
        patient.push(temp1.front());
        temp1.pop();
    }

    while (temp2.size() > 0) {
        patient.push(temp2.front());
        temp2.pop();
    }

    while (temp3.size() > 0)
    {
        patient.push(temp3.front());
        temp3.pop();
    }
}

void addPatient(){
    string text = "";
    PatientDetails pd;
    cin >> text;
    pd.ID = stoi(text);
    unorderedQueue.push(pd);
}
```

Comment: Step through the code with the debugger, and see when/where the data gets mangled.

Comment: I've been attempting to do that but so far haven't noticed anything. I think it might be within the sorting algorithm but can't tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem you're seeing is random garbage on the output. Stepping through the code with the debugger, you can see this happens even before the sort, as you (try to) output the values before calling the sort method.

That problem is caused by the line `cout << id.ID + " ";`.
What you want is `cout << id.ID << " ";`

Perhaps not the easiest thing to spot with the debugger; hopefully you'll have better luck fixing the sort itself.

Comment: Thanks, should have really spotted this myself. I've been working with c# and java for the past 6 weeks so I just got used to using the + to put together 2 strings. Still can't figure out the sorting algorithm though its been returning the first 3 ID's of the unordered array.

Comment: I just added a return type to the quickSortIDQueue and now it's returning the 3 IDs in order.

Comment: Look at `i` and the queue's size as you're going through the loops to output.

Comment: Got it. The queue size goes down when you pop it.